# unit testing extended class base functionality

Tags: oop, tdd, phpunit

I have an abstract Record class that represents records in the database. Each record must have at least the following columns: id, created, updated.

I then extend the Record class to represent rows in specific tables. For example, i have the following classes that extend Record: Customer, Job, Location, and Company. In each of these i define a static "table_name" variable and static variables that represent their columns.

I'd like to be able to test these classes for basic functionality that all extensions of Record should have. I could write a test class for each one to test for these things but i would basically be copying and pasting those tests for each extension of Record class which doesn't seem right.

I thought about writing a test class and and using a data provider with these objects in an array but i wouldn't know which object would cause the failure if there was a failing test.

There's got to be a way of having some sort of TestAllExtensionsOfRecordClass test class and then run my objects through it and be able to tell which object caused a failure.

Suggestions?

Comment: If what you want to test is an abstract class functionality - just create a stub-class that extends it and test it. And for particular class only test its particular implementation, assuming that base implementation is already tested.

Comment: Not understanding your choice of making the column variables static.  That's going to make unit testing hard. If each Record subclass is independent, you would test each independent subclass separately, but you would have at least one set of tests that test the base class functionality.  You wouldn't repeat testing "id" or "created" in each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Many unit testing frameworks support test class inheritance - you can create an abstract test superclass and all derived test classes will inherit and execute all tests in it. This allows you to define [abstract test cases aka contract tests](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractTestCases) in that superclass. These are tests for your "basic functionality" that must remain constant regardless of the concrete implementation. So in your case you would have an abstract RecordTest containing all basic test cases and derived CustomerTest, JobTest, etc. which will execute these tests against their own implementation.